# How to align labels in custom UITableViewCells?

Tags: ios, uitableview, storyboard

I like to use the built-in cell styles (right detail, basic, subtitle) as much as possible, but some times I need custom controls, like a `UISwitch` or a `UIStepper` to be added to the cell, and I have to create my own custom cell styles on Storyboard.

Since iOS 13 and 14 suggests using the cell's `imageView` is a good idea to be used for adding icons to the rows, I use it on cells with built-in styles. It seems the image view doesn't have a fixed width and the table view adapts itself to the widest image.

[image: iOS 13 icons]

What should I use to tie my `UITextLabel`s on my custom cells to in order to make advantage of this behavior? When I tie the left side of the label to the left margin, then the label overlaps the `imageView`.

[image: Storyboard]

Comment: I would strongly recommend not trying to mix-and-match "built-in" cells with custom cells. Is there a specific reason you don't want to use custom cells only?

Comment: Yes. Built-in styles adopt all the fancy features like responding to different size classes, adjusting margins on iPad, RTL languages, etc automatically. I would create a custom style only when it is really necessary.